# Releasing File Locks

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, movefile

I have a Background Worker run part of a program that loops through an array of files collated at runtime, doing various SQL tasks based on the file type etc.

One by one, as the files are dealt with, I want to move them to another folder so they are not accidentally reprocessed.

Some part of the process is locking the file(s) as the move command at the end of the loop is failing with a lock. What is the best way of releasing the lock (if there is one) and then moving the file? I considered copy then delete, but I suspect it will have the same issue with deleting the source file.

Count Files Sub ([source](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-FAQ/Multiple-Filters-Directory.GetFiles-Method.aspx))

```
Public Function count_files(ByVal location As String, ByVal Filter As String, ByVal searchOption As System.IO.SearchOption) As String()
        ' ArrayList will hold all file names
        Dim alFiles As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

    ' Create an array of filter string
    Dim MultipleFilters() As String = Filter.Split("|")

    ' for each filter find mathing file names
    For Each FileFilter As String In MultipleFilters
        ' add found file names to array list
        alFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(location, FileFilter, searchOption))
    Next

    ' returns string array of relevant file names
    Return alFiles.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.String"))
End Function
```

Background Worker code.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

'Count File Types, work out total & assign to progress bar length.
progress_total = sFiles.Count
current_count = 0

For Each FileName As String In sFiles
        current_count += 1
        currentfile = FileName
        filenamenoext = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName)
        extension = GetExtension(FileName)
        **DO STUFF HERE**

        'Report Progress

        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((current_count / progress_total) * 100))

        'If we've reached here, we've done something with the file. Move it so it cannot be reprocessed without manually moving the file.
        Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(currentfile, Import_Path & "processed\" & filenamenoext & extension, True)

        Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Moving File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End Try

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

Next

End Sub
```

The **DO STUFF HERE** does one of two things - read a .csv file into a `DataTable` (Data is written in using `FileIO.TextFieldParser`) or convert an image into byte code using `System.IO.MemoryStream`.

In both cases, the data is written into a SQLite table.

Comment: It's possible that whatever is happening in "** DO STUFF HERE**" is what is locking the file.  That is speculation since you did not provide any details of that code.

Comment: More data in the post above...

Comment: Fairly safe to assume that you've hidden the bug.  Notable is that MoveFile() doesn't actually care about locks, all it does is moving the directory entry and that can't be locked.  Unless you move it to a different disk drive, then it has to resort to a full copy and locks do act up.  Not something you'd normally favor.

Comment: Are you certain that when you read the .csv or open the file for the MemoryStream that you are properly closing all the files?  That would be my guess.

Comment: Chris, that is the problem. I've fixed the TextParser one by adding a `parser.close()` at the end of the loop, but I need to review the function that uses the `MemoryStream` to see the best place to close/dispose of it.

I think I might have to update it to use `USING`, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/5961665/1619795

Feel free to do a proper answer and i'll give you Best Answer credit.

Comment: A `MemoryStream` does not lock files on disk.

Comment: No, but another point in my code I was calling `Image.FromFile`, which I wasn't disposing off correctly. That's done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by Chris Dunaway, the answer was to `close()` the TextFieldParser and `Dispose` of the respective Image before trying to move the file.